# unable to install ddrescue

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, unity-dash, ddrescue

Im using the ubuntu 20.04 im trying to install ddrescue and ive tried most things ive seen here but i still get Unable to locate package .What coould be the issue .
ive updated the repository
enabled universal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install gddrescue on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251126/how-to-install-gddrescue-on-ubuntu-20-04)